# Fade 10 divs in and or out

Tags: html, fadein

In my example i want the divs fade in or out the problem is if i add .fadeIn(2000) or .fadeIn(slow) to the elements it doesnt work. How can somebody help me with this

http://jsfiddle.net/slider2nl/aCdRW/3/

```
var currPage = 'main';
function showPage(id) {
if (currPage !== null) {
    document.getElementById(currPage).style.display = 'none';
}
currPage = id;
document.getElementById(currPage).style.display = 'block';
}

var lastMove = new Date().getTime();
document.onmousemove = function() {
lastMove = new Date().getTime();
}
setInterval(function() {
var now = new Date().getTime();
if (now - lastMove > 10000) {
    showPage('main');
}
}, 1000);
```

Comment: To use fadeIn or fadeOu you need jQuery. Than just call `$("#your-id").fadeIn(2000)` or `$("#your-id").fadeOut(2000);`.

Comment: If i do that, it opens all my divs all at once. And i use mouseover. Also it always returns to the #main div

Comment: @R.deWilde can you post your updated code per Vinicius' suggestion? In your current code example or fiddle, there is nothing that will make DIVs fadeIn or fadeOut! As I understand, you are looking for a someone to help you find the problem in the code, not write the code for you, correct?

Comment: I tryed this first, http://jsfiddle.net/slider2nl/aCdRW/4/ so when you mouseover the links the div should fade in or out as you can see it doesnt work at all so i tryed them seprate with http://jsfiddle.net/slider2nl/aCdRW/5/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/slider2nl/aCdRW/11/ here is a better example of the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just updated your: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e3YDx/1/)

As I hope you can see, the Main is displayed after 2 seconds, and when you move over one of the links at the top, the pages are displayed.

```
var currPage = 'main';
function showPage(id) {
    if (currPage !== null) {
        $("#"+currPage).fadeOut(500);
    }
    currPage = id;
    $("#"+currPage).fadeIn(500);
}

var lastMove = new Date().getTime();
document.onmousemove = function() {
    lastMove = new Date().getTime();
}
setInterval(function() {
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    if (now - lastMove > 60000) {
        showPage('main');
    }
}, 1000);

$(document).ready(function () {
$('#main').hide();
$('#main').delay(2000).fadeIn(500);

});
```

Comment: I have tested it but the main keeps fade in and out every 60 seconds? it only need to return to the main if there is no mousemove

Comment: That part I just copied from your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/slider2nl/aCdRW/4/ if that is not what you wanted, let me know exactly and I'll fix it.

Comment: This is wat it needs to do i have 9 divs with content and 1 as  main/start div when mousover the 9 divs it shows the content but when there is no mousemove a settimeout is set to return to te main/start div. also another settimeout checks if there is mousemove. i want to add a fade in and out effect on the 9 or more divs not on main/start div that needs to be instant show or hide  without effect. If i turn on jquery 1.9.1 on in fiddle the script works but no fade in or out http://jsfiddle.net/slider2nl/aCdRW/13/

Comment: Any idea what it could be?

Comment: dont't you mean that the main should be shown when the mouse move out of a lable?

Comment: no thats is not what i meant, i really need a solution to get the divs to fade in and out, but not the main div

Comment: Hope I finally understood it hehehe... am I at the right road now? http://jsfiddle.net/e3YDx/2/